# Android SQLite forbidden characters 

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, symbols

I am trying to insert some string into my SQLite database that have these (') in them. for some reason, it is messing my query.

Is there a way to insert symbols into the database without destroying the query?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the middle of a string, use two single quotes next to each other to include a single quote in a string.

Try this

```
String updateString = "UPDATE " + DATABASE_CASTING + " SET " + KEY_PROTECT + "='" + value + "' WHERE " + KEY_NAME + "='" + name + "' AND " + KEY_TOTAL + "='" + total +"'";

ourDatabase.execSQL(updateString);
```

Comment: ourDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE " + DATABASE_CASTING + " SET " + KEY_PROTECT + " = '" + value + "' WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " =" + name + " AND " + KEY_TOTAL + " = '" + total + "';");

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
String strreplace = "your query with ' & " character";
String result = strreplace .replaceAll("'", "''");
result = result .replaceAll(""", """");
```

This will replace **'** with **''(these are two)** and **"** with **""**

Comment: it doesn't compile well... what does str mean?

Comment: This str.replaceAll gives a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the strings before you put them into your query and replace any `'` with `''`.